# jQuery hover event handler not working on dynamic content while click does

Tags: javascript, jquery

For dynamically created content, I am using the 'on' method to handle events. That works fine with click but not with hover.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert('a');
});
```

Works but

```
$(document).on('hover', 'li', function(){
    alert('a');
});
```

does not.

Is the code wrong? Or the problem arises cause of something else on my setup.

Comment: Hover is no real js event, its a jquery function. Thats why its not working.

Comment: delgates don't support hover event use mouse enter, mouse leave event . `$(document).on(mouseenter: function(){}, mouseleave: function{}, 'li');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["hover" pseudo-event](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event)

> As of 1.9, the event name string "hover" is no longer supported as a synonym for "mouseenter mouseleave"

You need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
    alert('a');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', 'li', function(){
    alert('a');
});
```

You can also use alternate syntax

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {           
    },
    mouseleave: function () {           
    }}, "li");
```

Comment: Thanks. didn't know that hover can not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method

You should use `mouseenter`

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
    alert('a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>sdada</li>
  </ul>
```